# Visual studio 2012 debug stops during debug session (time out)

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2012

When i debug on VS2012, when i stay idle on a certain function, the debugger "time out" and suddenly the debugger stops the session.
How could i know why this happens ?
Can i view debugger logs ?

i tried to put the function content in try {} catch() {} and when it stopped debugging it did not catch any exception, simply stopped debugging.

Comment: Did you check the debugger log? It's in the Output window, in "Show output from:" dropdown, select "Debug"

Comment: The program '[7940] MainGUI.vshost.exe: Managed (v4.0.30319)' has exited with code -2147023895 (0x800703e9).

Comment: You should try searching for that exit code. My searching suggests that it has something to do with a stack overflow, possibly due to recursion, but I don't know how much that helps.

Comment: thanks i will lookup into it.

Comment: Thank you, you were right there has been a recursive in the code, the odd thing it didnt throw exception although the System exception while debugging was with "Thrown"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as Cong Xu commented, There was a recursive call in the code.